# Достучаться до элемента хеша

Tags: perl

Добрый день.

Есть sub'a, первым параметром в которую передается хеш, но не просто, а мудрено.
Если его вывести через Dumper, то видим, что он внутри bless (читал, читал, но так и не понял, как это практически понять:)))

```
use Data::Dumper;
sub test{
print Dumper shift
}
```

Вывод

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
             'protocol' => 114,
             'cb' => 'envrcpt',
             'socket' => bless( \*Symbol::GEN2, 'IO::Socket::INET' ),
             'callbacks' => {
                              'envrcpt' => sub { "DUMMY" }
                            },
             'reply' => undef,
             'callback_flags' => 31,
             'symbols' => {
                            'M' => {
                                     '{auth_author}' => 'sender@domain.tld',
                                     '{mail_mailer}' => 'local'
                                   }
                           }
                 }, 'Sendmail:PMilter::Context' );
```

Как бы подступиться к этим полям? 
Хотелось бы `print var{'symbols'}{'M'}{'auth_author'}` и получить то, что надо.

Comment: "Perl |" - лучше стереть я думаю это не корректно...

Comment: чё это вдруг..

Comment: Уже исправили :). Потому что когда заходишь в вопрос тег подставляется в тайтл и получается что то вроде "perl - Perl|Достучаться до элемента хеша".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Может быть проще использовать готовый пакет [Sendmail:PMilter::Context](http://search.cpan.org/~avar/Sendmail-PMilter-1.00/lib/Sendmail/PMilter/Context.pm), там есть метод `getsymval`. Напимер:

```
use Sendmail:PMilter::Context;

sub test {
    my $tx = shift;

    print $tx->getsymval('{auth_author}')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Блеснутый хеш - это объект и наверняка есть методы для работы с его полями, лазить внтурь такого хеша очень не хорошо. Но если очень хочется:

```
my $sym = shift;
warn $sym->{'symbols'}->{'M'}->{'{auth_author}'};
```

Comment: если смотреть dumperом то видно содержимое, print же игнорирует.. но вы правы в главном, не стоит так, буду через методы подступаться

Answer (score 1):

```
use Data::Dumper;
sub test {
    my $t = shift;
    print $t->{protocol};
}
```